# SQL query using EXIST operator - unexpected records in result

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using the AdventureWorks2014 database, I was experimenting with the EXIST keyword. Please note the following query:

```
select p.color, p.productid, p.name, th.Quantity
from production.product p, production.TransactionHistory th
where p.ProductID=th.ProductID and EXISTS(
  select *
  from Production.TransactionHistory t
  where t.Quantity = 1000
  and t.ProductID=p.ProductID
)
```

I was expecting to see only products that were ordered 1000 at a time (there is only one transaction that meets this condition), but instead I get hundreds of rows where th.Quantity is < 1000.

Removing the joined TransactionHistory table from the outer query solves the problem, but I just want to know why the original query returns the rows I am seeing.

Thanks

Edit:

For clarification, I understand how to solve the question that I want. I just wanted to understand the behavior of EXISTS and why I'm not getting the results I expected.

The following subquery (which is part of the EXISTS subquery), only returns a single result.

```
select *
from Production.TransactionHistory t
where t.Quantity = 1000
```

Therefore, if this is inside EXISTS it will return true every time. The caveat is that I am linking t.ProductID with p.ProductID in the subquery. So, for every row in the outer query, the product ID should be matching the product ID in the inner query. EXISTS should only return true when the product ID matches and the quantity is exactly 1000. To be precise, EXIST should only return true when the product ID is 994, because there is only one transaction in the entire table (with that product ID) that satisfies both the product ID requirement and the 1000 quantity requirement.

Notice the rest of the EXISTS subquery...

```
where t.Quantity = 1000 and t.ProductID=p.ProductID
```

The product ID has to match the outer record's product ID AND the quantity must be 1000.

To me, this query says "Give me the color, product id and name of all products, join in transactions, and then only include each row where there is at least one record in the transaction table whose product id matches the id of the CURRENT outer row, AND the order quantity is 1000". But this is not how it behaves. Just trying to understand why.

Comment: For clarification, I understand how to solve the question that I want. I just wanted to understand the behavior of EXISTS and why I'm not getting the results I expected.

Comment: In a simple test I don't get unexpected results. Can you provide sample data? Your query is returning all records from the product to history join that have at least one history record with a quantity of 1000. So if you're seeing multiple records for productid 994, that makes sense because there's at least one with quantity 1000, if you're seeing other product id's that doesn't make sense.

Comment: The product ID was the same but I was getting results where there were transaction with qty <> 1000. I figured out what was going on by looking at the query plan. Essentially, the subquery returns 1 row which makes exists true, but since that product ID has hundreds of other transactions, they were being linked in the join in the outer query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query sounds like this:

> Get all transaction history entries of product if any of history entry have
>   Quantity equal to 1000.

`EXISTS` return true or false, so

```
EXISTS(
    select *
    from Production.TransactionHistory t
    where t.Quantity = 1000
    and t.ProductID=p.ProductID
)
```

will return true for all TransactionHistory rows of product which have Transaction with Quantity = 1000

In addition:
Query above will be executed for every row of "Main" query and will return `True` on every row in your case. Thats why you get all rows

Comment: So the t.ProductID=p.ProductId is not matched? There is only one product in the entire database that matches to a transaction with a quantity of 1000. Thank you.

Comment: But how much rows that product has in Transaction History table? Your query return all that rows

Comment: There are 442 rows in transaction table that match that product ID. However, there is only one row where the product id matches and the quantity is 1000.

Answer (score 0):

`EXISTS` returns true if the following query has even one record in it.
You are looking for a query something like below:

```
SELECT p.color, p.productid, p.name, th.Quantity
FROM production.product p, production.TransactionHistory th
WHERE p.ProductID = th.ProductID and th.Quantity = 1000
```

OR you can replace it with a better looking `join` query which looks like this:

```
SELECT p.color, p.productid, p.name, th.Quantity
FROM production.product p
INNER JOIN production.TransactionHistory th ON p.ProductID = th.ProductID 
WHERE th.Quantity = 1000
```

Comment: Thanks Chaos, appreciate the help. Can you perhaps read through my edit above? I totally get the right way to do the query, but I want to understand why my experimental query failed.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are checking only ProductID in EXIST clause. When it finds at least one transaction with your productID then it displays such transaction. So all transactions for product that has transaction with quantity equals to 1000 will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

basically your query is saying

> Give me all product and it's transaction history WHERE there is
>   **EVER** a transaction with quantity of 1000